# Create a button to Impersonate and search as a specific user

Tags: apex, experience-cloud, identity, coveo

My organization uses the Coveo search engine to index and search content from multiple systems.

Not all customers in our community have the same permissions, so it is helpful for our support agents to log into the customer experience as the customer to ensure that the customer has access to the documents and knowledge articles they want to recommend.

There are too many clicks, page loads and wait times for this to be efficient when we have to open the contact, log in as the user, navigate to the search page, find the resources, log out, post the results.

I would like to add a button on the agent case view that would just automatically open up the customer experience search page, logged in as the customer who submitted that case.

Is there any way to do this?  Or am I stuck just going through the multi-step process I outlined above?  I'm thinking something like this, but where I generate a URL for the specific page in the community that auto-logs-in-as someone.
https://medium.com/smartbox-engineering/impersonating-salesforce-users-in-test-frameworks-903b7de597c0

Answer (score 0):

When indexing documents with Coveo, as you mention, it respects the original permissions on that content within Salesforce for example (same for more other systems).

So if you login by impersonating another user as described in the article you mentioned it should give you the same content that user would actually see in the community since you are in effect logged in as that user.

I am not familiar with how to reverse-engineer the impersonate process as the article you linked seems to be doing to generate the url. But if the end result is that you are logged in the community as that user, then it should do the trick with Coveo search as well!